# XAML combine styles with styles from toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I use the [Adonis UI](https://github.com/benruehl/adonis-ui) black theme for my styles and it makes all controls look great.

Now, for a ListBox I need to add a custom style

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
       </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

but this removes some of the Adonis UI style from the ListBoxItem (the white font to be precise).

I also tried adding the style to my ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AdonisUI;component/ColorSchemes/Dark.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AdonisUI.ClassicTheme;component/Resources.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But that doesn't work at all.

How can I combine those Styles?

Comment: Use `<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ...}" ...>`  with the AdonisUI ListBox Style resource as base.

Comment: @Clemens Oh wow I've tried that before but now it works. Thank you!